# Function not being called while in another function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently working on a blackjack project for my final exam in my programming class at school but I'm currently having trouble running a function while its in another one. What I want to happen is that if the list of cards I shuffle through has a king, queen, jack or ace in it I want your points to go up by the correct amount. For some reason though, the program just ignores those values in the list and jumps to the next integer. Here is the list ['Ace',2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'Valet','Dame','Roi']

```
def valeurs(somme,main):
    ace = 'Ace'
    dame = 'Dame'
    roi = 'Roi'
    valet = 'Valet'
    for ace in main:
        if somme <= 10:
             somme += 11
        else:
            somme += 1
    for dame in main:
        somme += 10
    for roi in main:
        somme += 10
    for valet in main:
        somme += 10

def jeu(carte,somme):
    nombreCarte = 0
    compteur = 0
    while nombreCarte < 5 and somme < 21 or somme < 21:
        main.append(carte[compteur])
        if main[compteur] == 'Ace' or main[compteur] == 'Dame' or 
           main[compteur] == 'Roi' or main[compteur] == 'Valet':
            valeurs(somme,main)
            nombreCarte += 1
        else:
            if type(main[compteur]) != int:
                valeurs(somme,main)
            else:
                somme += main[compteur]
                nombreCarte += 1
        compteur += 1
    print (main,somme)
```

Comment: `nombreCarte < 5 and somme < 21 or somme < 21` makes no sense -- the last two conditions are identical.

Answer (score 0):

When you have `for ace in main:` (and also for the other three loops) this will iterate through main and make ace equal to each element in main just like `for i in range(10)` would make i equal to the numbers 0-9. I don't know the rules of black jack, but what I think you're trying to do is:

```
for i in main:
    if i==ace:
        if somme <= 10:
            somme += 11
        else:
            somme += 1
```

and then apply the same change to the other for loops.

Answer (score 0):

The function `valeurs` contains a semantic error. Specifically the lines:

```
ace = 'Ace'
    ...
for ace in main:
        if somme <= 10:
             somme += 11
        else:
            somme += 1
```

In the for loop above, `ace` is assigned a temporary value that corresponds
to the current item in the list during each iteration.
The implication of this is that `somme` is the body of the loop is incremented according to the value of `somme` without taking into consideration wether the hand is actually an ace as defined in `ace = 'Ace'`

The same holds for the `dame`, `roi` and `valet` cards.

This is because in python, a `for loop` operates as a `foreach loop` See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop for details.

On way to fix this is the following

```
for card in main:
    if card == ace and somme <=10:
        somme += 11
    elif card == ace and somme > 10:
        somme += 1
    elif card in (dame, roi, valet):
        somme += 10
```

like @John Gordon said, the condition `nombreCarte < 5 and somme < 21 or somme < 21`
should be refactored to something like:
`nombreCarte < 5 and somme < 21`.
A lot more can be said but this should get you going

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps for corrections/modifications

```
def valeurs(main):
    somme = 0

    # add all values that do not change
    for carte in main:
        if cart != 'Ace'
            if cart == 'Dame' or cart == 'Roi' or cart =='Valet':
                somme += 10
            else:
                somme += int(cart)           #if it a string, no issue

    # your code always adds 11 for the first ace, and then 1 after
    #    this can be a problem if you have 2 'Ace' and a 'Dame'!
  # card order: ace, ace, ace, 9
  #11 + 1 + 1 + 9 = 22 OR 9 + 1 + 1 + 1 + (0 if greater than 12, 10 if less)
  #                                  12 + (0)
  #       a) 22 -> bust
  #       b) 12 -> no bust
  # now add values that may change! (1 or 11)
    somme += main.count('Ace')
    if main.count('Ace') > 0 and somme < 12:
        somme += 10

    return somme

def jeu(carte):
    main = []                                 # where did you declare 
                                              #    main to be a list?
                                              #   can't main.append 
    while valuers(main) < 21 and len(main) < 5:
                                              # no need for 'nombreCarte'
                                              #    - len(main) does it 
                                              # does main length matter?
        main.append(carte(as_hasard))         #append only strings? 
                                              #main.append(str(as_hasard)) 
                                              #replace cart(comptuer)?
    [print (str(carte)) for carte in main]    #print all values in hand
    if len(main) >= 5 and valuers(main) <= 21:# check results
        print ("5 carte - no bust win")
    else:
        print valuers(main)
```

*added*
It was bugging me and I came back and found it.

```
valeurs(somme,main)
```

The valeurs() call does NOT change the value of somme in the jeu() function
have valeurs() return somme, then you can use this

```
somme = valeurs(somme, main)
```